# fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[ { code: 71, message: 'Authorization failure' } ]]

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Failed to register the username NpPharma for organization Manufacturer with::fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[ { code: 71, message: 'Authorization failure' } ]]

connection-manufacturer.js ->

```
{
"name": "artifacts-test-manufacturer",
"version": "1.0.0",
"client": {
    "organization": "Manufacturer",
    "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "peer": {
                "endorser": "300"
            }
        }
    }
},
"organizations": {
    "Manufacturer": {
        "mspid": "ManufacturerMSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.manufacturer.example.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "ca.manufacturer.example.com"
        ]
    }
},
"peers": {
    "peer0.manufacturer.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nFTDhFDO5DzeKVg==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        },
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.manufacturer.example.com",
            "hostnameOverride": "peer0.manufacturer.example.com"
        }
    }


},
"certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.manufacturer.example.com": {
        "url": "https://localhost:7054",
        "caName": "ca.manufacturer.example.com",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nFTDhFDO5DzeKVg==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        },
        "httpOptions": {
            "verify": false
        }
    }
}
```

}

function to register the user

```
const ca = new FabricCAServices(caInfo.url, { trustedRoots: caTLSCACerts, verify: false }, caInfo.caName);
const secret = await ca.register({
      affiliation: 'manufacturer.department1',
      enrollmentID: username,
      role: 'client'
    }, adminUser);
```

Comment: What roles does `adminUser` have?

Comment: I didn't get the question clearly, adminUser here is **admin** identity, which i enrolled admin using 'fabric-ca-client'.Also, admin.id is in wallet

Comment: also, I got the problem resolved when i changed the affiliation to 'org1.department1' .
Can you tell me why this happens?

Comment: When I checked one of the files generated after creating network with ca, i.e, fabric-ca-server-config.yaml for the organisation "manufacturer", I found the affiliations as org1.department1, org2.department2 , event though I didn't mention them anywhere.Can you tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: See my answer below.  The affiliation must exist for you to add users to it.  The default config generated for Fabric CA server includes a few affiliations by default ( https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/main/cmd/fabric-ca-server/config.go#L273-L278 ) , which is why you see them and why you were able to add a user with one of those affiliations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to make sure that the affiliation `manufacturer.department1` has been created.  You can either create the affiliation by including it the `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` file or by creating via the CLI (or one of the SDKs) after the Fabric CA has been initialized and is running.

To include it in your [config](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/serverconfig.html), you'll need to add a stanza like

```
affiliations:
   manufacturer:
      - department1
```

to your Fabric CA server config file.

To [create the affiliation with the CLI](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#dynamically-updating-affiliations):

```
fabric-ca-client affiliation add manufacturer.department1
```

You will also need to make sure that the admin user has the `hf.AffiliationMgr` attribute set to true.  The admin must also either have it's affiliation set to `""` (meaning the admin can manage all affiliations) or to the specific affiliation or any of it's parents.  The default admin user can manage all affiliations.